# Virtual interface wont change state under KVM when physical interface goes down

Tags: redhat, kvm

How to change the passthrough behavior and reflect the state of the physical interface when it goes down within the virtual machine?

Currently, when the physical interface is down, the passthrough remains up. I understand that this is the expected behavior, but I want it to go down when the physical interface is also down.

Any ideas?
Thanks.